# Why are my vectors becoming a list upon integrating the integers equal to or over 12?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, integration

Why are my vectors becoming a list upon integrating the integers equal to or over 12?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `?integrate`, the return value is a list with a few different values in it. The actual estimated value is stored at `result$value`. So if you pull that value out of the result you get your expected result:

```
integrand <- function(x) sqrt(x)
for(i in seq(from=1, to=20, length=20)) {
    VectorY[i] <- i #Creates Vector List 1:20
    if(VectorY[i] < 12) {
        VectorY[i] <- cos(3*i) # replaces 1:11 with 3cosin
    } else {
        if(VectorY[i] >= 12) {
            VectorY[i] <- integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = i)$value
        }
    }
}
```